# Requestee user cannot remove a one way User Relationship with requester user

Tags: 7, users

I have a one-way User Relationship which also can be reciprocated, and I have run into an issue where users cannot remove a one-way relationship with another user that they have previously approved.

For example, User B sends a one-way relationship request to User A. User A approves it. Then, User A decides they no longer want to have that relationship with User B, and they click the link to remove that relationship (for example, https://mywebsite.com/user/778/relationships/requested/3338/remove). The relationship is not removed, and User A is presented with this message: "No action has been taken". There is nothing in the Recent Log Messages that would point to any specific issue, and all of the Have/Maintain/Request/Delete permissions are enabled for Authenticated and other specific user roles that these users have.

How can I fix this, so that User A has total control over which approved relationships they have with User B?

Comment: To add a bit more detail... when User A visits their "My Relationships" page (mysite.com/relationships), the "Operations" column is blank. Why would this relationship be "permanent" like this?

Answer (score 0):

I applied the patch listed here (https://www.drupal.org/node/1328170#comment-6980582) and that resolved the issue.